# Why doesn't my custom DisplayFor template actually get rendered here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model:

```
public class PostModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Idea")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and I've created a custom display for it in `/Shared/DisplayTemplates/PostModel.ascx`. I then display a listing of these on the `Home/Index` view:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Popular)
{
    Html.DisplayFor(m => p);
}
```

When stepping through the view, if I *step into* the `Html.DisplayFor`, I get into the `/Shared/DisplayTemplates/PostModel.ascx` and it gets processed as expected. However, it never actually gets rendered.

What did I miss?

Here is the template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="PostModel.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TPB.Models.PostModel>" %>

<div class="rounded-border">
    <h2><%= Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Title) %></h2>
    <p><%= Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Body) %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: From my understanding you can't mix Razor with the classic engine.

Comment: @Aron, that's actually how the `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` methods work. They look for `ascx` files. I was just missing the `@`.

Comment: You are mixing between the Classic ViewEngine and the Razor View Engine. You are correct that `HtmlHelper.DisplayFor` and `HtmlHelper.EditorFor` should resolve the correct template, and it will look for templates in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/{classname}.{extension}`. It shouldn't move between View Engines. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Comment: @Aron, and have you implemented a `DisplayFor` with a `cshtml` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Dai was close.  Response.Write should be not be used for this.  You need the @ sign in front to tell Razor that the returned value should be rendered into the page.

This should work:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Popular) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => p);
}
```

In my tests in other projects, you shouldn't even really need the loop if all you are doing is displaying all members of an IEnumerable (list, array, etc.).

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Popular);
```

has worked for me.

Comment: And this was exactly what I needed. And yes, the latter works just fine on an entire collection!

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayFor` returns an instance of `MvcHtmlString`, it doesn't actually write anything to the response stream.

You'll want this:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Popular) {
    Response.Write( Html.DisplayFor(m => p) );
}
```

Comment: Though that did cause it to be rendered, it was actually rendered at the top of the screen. Likely because `Response.Write` doesn't actually pay attention to the DOM.

Comment: The DOM has nothing to do with it. Are you calling `DisplayFor` within another piece of code that writes to an MvcHtmlString instead of to the response stream?

Comment: I'm inside of a view. The `/Home/Index` view. And I'm trying to render a collection of these models.